# How to use Global Variables in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, global-variables

Here is my code

```
public partial class Books : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    String Book_CategoryName = "";
    String Book_SubCategoryName = "";

   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            Book_CategoryName = "Education";
        }
    }
    public void BookDataLinkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("Data Found :: "+Book_CategoryName);
    }

}
```

In this code i use global variable, on page_load set the value of Book_CategoryName variable and try to get on LinkButton click. But i am unable to get the "**Education**" . When i run this code it show me **Data Found ::**

How can i get the value of Book_CategoryName  variable.

Try to help me out of this problem.

Comment: i also check this code without !Page.IsPostBack but result is still same. string is empty

Comment: Note that code you've posted *does not* show any global variables (`static` properties in C#). Probably missing something in sample OR you use "global" in some other meaning.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov He most probably meant "global variable" as a class variable.

Comment: @JWLim Clearly you mean that OP mean "how to get data into session state and read on next request"... It is hard to know why someone said something - little clarification from OP could be useful...

Comment: yes i meant global variable as a class variable. Thanks for giving your precious time. Now problem is solved by using static variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On each post back, the instance of Page(Books) is re-created, so you will not get the value of Book_CategoryName after button click.
An approch is to store the variable in ViewState.

```
private const string KEY_Book_CategoryName = "Book_CategoryName";
public String Book_CategoryName
{
    get
    {
        return ViewState[KEY_Book_CategoryName] as string;
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState[KEY_Book_CategoryName] = value;
    }
}
```

The other approch can be store the value in a hidden field of the page. The idea is to store the value somewhere that can persistent during post back.

Comment: +1 Note that view state is stored in hidden field on page already. Alternative approach is to store data in session state (just use `Session` instead of `ViewState` in sample).

Answer (score 1):

That's because the page object called is different for each web request. Hence, when you initialize `Book_CategoryName` in Page_Load, it is only valid for that request and the value is lost in the next request i.e. when BookDataLinkButton_Click is called.

In your case, you could simply initialize the variable during declaration, like so:

```
String Book_CategoryName = "Education";
```

You can take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989077/class-variable-losing-value) for more information.

Alternatively, you can use the `ViewState` instead of a "global variable"

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (!Page.IsPostBack)
     {
         ViewState["Book_CategoryName"] = "Education";
     }
}

public void BookDataLinkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Response.Write("Data Found :: " + (string)ViewState["Book_CategoryName"]);
}
```

Comment: so how can i use the global variables for more than one request ?

Comment: @Kushal use the `ViewState`. I've edited my answer with information on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Change your variable like following

```
static String Book_CategoryName = "";    
static String Book_SubCategoryName = "";
```

Comment: If i make this variable static, then i cannot use this variable in button click.